# About block $\mathcal{O}_\lambda$ of Category $\mathcal{O}$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, weights

The blocks of $\mathcal{O}$ are precisely the subcategories consisting of modules whose composition factors all have highest weights linked by $W_{[\lambda]}$ to an
antidominant weight $\lambda$.

I would like to know that whether $M\in\mathcal{O}_\lambda$ implies the submodules/quotients of $M$ also lie in $\mathcal{O}_\lambda$?

Comment: Yes, this follows trivially from the description you just gave, since submodules and quotients have the same possible composition factors.

Comment: Can you elaborate why submodules and quotients have the same possible composition factors, please?

Comment: Because all composition series are equivalent up to rearrangement (and all modules here have finite length). This is Jordan-Hölder.

Comment: According to what I know, Jordan-Hölder theorem is about composition series of $M$. But now I am concerning about composition series of $N$ where $N$ is a submodule/quotient of $M$.

Comment: And Jordan-Hölder says that these form a subset of the ones from $M$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. Let me search the version of Jordan-Hölder theorem that you have mentioned.

Comment: @‍JamesCheung, [@TobiasKildetoft's statement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311353/about-block-mathcalo-lambda-of-category-mathcalo/311368#comment776522_311353) is not a separate version of Jordan–Hölder, but a statement about a composition series of a subquotient of a module that already has a composition series (which is entirely unrelated to the question of whether such a series exists).  [You](https://mathoverflow.net/a/311368) prove the statement for submodules below, and the argument for quotients is basically the same.

Comment: @James: You are making the early exercises too complicated, I think (though you may be the first person to attempt them all).     These were meant to be "easy", though may have been misstated.     Be sure to consult the errata on my homepage.

Answer (score 2):

Submodules/quotients have the same (edit: generalized) infinitesimal character. Now use [Harish-Chandra theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harish-Chandra_isomorphism).

EDIT: Definitely an overkill. Easier solution is in the comments of the question.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Humphreys defines these infinitesimal blocks precisely using generalized(!) infinitesimal character and then the OPs characterization follows from H-Ch theorem. From that viewpoint your answer seems better.

Comment: Submodules/quotients have the same infinitesimal character and then use Harish-Chandra theorem just tell us that $M\in\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$ implies submodule/quotient of $M$ also lie in $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$. Now we are considering $\mathcal{O}_\mu$ where $\mu$ is an antidominant weight. According to Humphreys' Book, $\mathcal{O}_\mu$ is a refinement of the subcategory $\mathcal{O}_{\chi_\lambda}$ for some $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M=M_0\supseteq M_1\supseteq \cdots \supseteq M_l=\{0\}$ be a composition series of length $l$.

Let $N$ be a submodule of $M$. Then $N=N\cap M_0\supseteq N\cap M_1\supseteq \cdots \supseteq N\cap M_l=\{0\}$ is a chain of submodule from $N$ to $\{0\}$.

By module isomorphism, $\dfrac{N\cap M_i}{N\cap M_{i+1}}=\dfrac{N\cap M_i}{(N\cap M_i)\cap M_{i+1}}\cong \dfrac{N\cap M_i+M_{i+1}}{M_{i+1}}$ which is a submodule of the simple module $\dfrac{M_i}{M_{i+1}}$. Hence $\dfrac{N\cap M_i}{N\cap M_{i+1}}$ is trivial or simple.

By deleting repetition from the chain, we get a composition series for $N$. Meanwhile, the set of composition factors for $N$ is a subset of that for $M$.

Therefore, $M\in\mathcal{O}_\lambda$ implies the **submodules** of M also lie in $\mathcal{O}_\lambda$.

How about the case for quotients of $M$?

Comment: The same argument applies, except that you project to the quotient instead of intersecting with the submodule.

Comment: What is about sum/direct sum of modules? Given $M,N\in\mathcal{O}_\lambda$, whether $M+N\in \mathcal{O}_\lambda$ and whether $M\oplus N\in \mathcal{O}_\lambda$?

Comment: This is a routine exercise that you can do for yourself.  The case of direct sums is straightforward, and the case of (possibly non-direct) sums can be dealt with, for example, by viewing such a sum as the quotient of a direct sum.